# Struct Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'Continents'?

Tags: ios, swift, drop-down-menu, uilabel

Struct can find in ViewController.
The error show  `Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'Continents'?`
this massage.

```
struct Continents {
      var continents_name_list : String
}
```

This is a drop-down menu code:

```
func getDataToDropDown(cell: UITableViewCell, indexPos: Int, makeDropDownIdentifier: String) {
    if makeDropDownIdentifier == "DROP_DOWN_NEW"{
        let customCell = cell as! DropDownTableViewCell
        customCell.countryNameLabel.text = self.Continents[indexPos]
        print("test")
    }
}

func numberOfRows(makeDropDownIdentifier: String) -> Int {
    return self.Continents.count
}

func selectItemInDropDown(indexPos: Int, makeDropDownIdentifier: String) {
    self.continente_text_label.text = "\(self.Continents[indexPos])"
    self.dropDown.hideDropDown()
}
```

Frist:

[image: Frist:]

Last:

[image: Last:]

Comment: Replace `self.Continents` with `self.continents_list` to fix the errors.

Comment: I assume you want the struct Continents to contain an array of strings. At the moment it will only receive a string.

Comment: My last advice would be to use an enum instead of a struct to store my continents.

Comment: Continent Is a type (like Int, String, etc...).
This means you can create arrays, variables, etc. of type Continents.
Calling Continents.count is like calling Int.count which means nothing.
This is why it won't work. If you want to get the count of your array, you'll have to write the name of your array.count. In your case continents_list.count.

Comment: I assume you want the struct Continents to contain an array of strings. At the moment it will only receive a string.

Comment: Who are you talking to, this is your question?

Answer (score 1):

`Continents` Is a type (like Int, String ecc...).
This means you can create arrays, variables etc. of type Continents.
Calling `Continents.count` is like calling `Int.count` which means nothing.
This is why it won't work. If you want to get the count of your array, you'll have to write the name of your array.count. In your case `continents_list.count`.

Anyway there are a few semantical errors in your code so I'll give you a few suggestions.

1. I assume you want the struct Continents to contain an array of strings. At the moment it will only receive a string. Try this instead:

```swift
struct Continents {
      var continents_name_list : [String]
}
```

2. Furthermore, the `continents_list` array you created is of type String, you should declare it like this if you want it to be of type Continents:

```swift
var continents_list = Continents(continents_name_list: ["c1", "c2", "cn"])
```

3. My last advice would be to use an enum instead of a struct to store your continents.

```swift
enum Continents {
    case Europe
    case America
    case Africa
    case Antartica
    case Asia
    case Oceania
}
```